# Efiiciency for Pagination in Java

Tags: java, pagination

I am writing Pagination for a set of records in Java. Here i am talking to a service which fetches a result set of 500 per time. I interact with that service to display at most 50 records at a time with page markers.

Is it a really efficient model or if there is any other way to improve the suggested pagination model ?

Comment: "...the following pagination model ?" - There's nothing following this sentence.  To what model do you refer?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that he meant the opposite of "following" as there is nothing following that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data.

If your data is rapidly changing, this definitely isn't a suitable method. I would suggest tweaking the service to return only as much requested records that are needed by the page.

If data is static and need not be time dependent, this should work fine. Just fetch the 500 records, put it in a local array and display from there. Once this is exhausted, replenish the same.